# How to make vanity URLs for Profile pages

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to make www.profstream.com/profile-t.php?username=arunsood -> www.profstream.com/arunsood for example. My links are all set up on my site to visit the original URL, but I just want it to show up like the rewritten example in the address bar and be called when someone types in www.profstream.com/arunsood for example.

This is the mod rewrite rule suggested to me but it just says nothing is found when I try it out:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /profile-t.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Is there a way to make it work without changing the link structure already on the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile-t.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Awesome man! Thanks so much. Now, how would I get it to show the correct (rewritten) URL when I click on a link from the site?

Comment: as i understand you don't want to change your links in html ?

Comment: That's right... so I guess there's no choice then? Thanks for your answer though, it was very helpful :)